# How can I execute a C program without creating a copy of said file?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, raspberry-pi

I hope your having a wonderful morning. I was on the Raspberry Pi website, and downloaded an issue of MagPi that taught you how to get started in the C language, and I'm so exited! The instructions told me to make a file, name it `hello.c`, and then put in the terminal command `gcc -o myprog /home/pi/Desktop/C/hello.c` to make the program executable. Once this step ended, it told me that to run it, you write `./myprog`, then it executes. When I changed the program up so it did something else, and I ran the code again, it printed the version that I hadn't changed up. When I ran the gcc command, It did change, but created a new project on the desktop for it. I don't want my raspberry flooded with hello world c programs, so if there is a way not to get it to clone itself, please let me know. A little long winded, but I hope it explains my situation.

Comment: Uh, have you considered reading a tutorial about C? C is a compiled language, you have to run the compiler first to turn your code into an executable. And what do you mean by *"flooded with hello world c programs"*? Why would you suddenly have multiple copies of the same code/executable?

Comment: Because every time I go to rerun the program with the changes with gcc -o myprog /home/pi/Desktop/C/hello.c it creates a copy.

Comment: What do you mean by *"a copy"*? If you use the same command (from the same directory) then it should overwrite the old executable. So how do these copies look like?

Comment: Another C project with the changes I made show up on the desktop, but dont overwrite the old one.

Comment: What is *"Another C project"*? The source files? Or another executable with a different name (if yes what is the name and what happens to the old one)?

Comment: Wait, its fixed because of the answer below. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I tried it again and it didnt put one on the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you compile the program, the generated executable is written in the folder you are in.

E.g. if you are in
/home/pi/
And you run your command, you'll get an hello executable in the same folder

You use -o parameter to tell where to store the output executable, but you should provide a full path.

E.g.

## to create the destination folder

mkdir -p /home/pi/Desktop/C/bin/

## to build

gcc -o /home/pi/Desktop/C/bin/myprog /home/pi/Desktop/C/hello.c

Comment: When I run the exe in the .bin folder it does nothing. Is it because I need to define that pathway?

Comment: When I execute in the terminal it opens the terminal and quickly closes it.

Answer (score 0):

to execute `c files` you have to make it executable by machine by converted to `.o` files and this is the mission of compiler .then the  files with `.o` are compiled object files that first need to be linked to become an executable .

[image]

don't care about `.h` files in picture it's just headers files

> the main answer : every time you changed your file you have to compile
>   it again to get the output !!! mean use gcc every time !!

note :
you don't have to use gcc the way you do in the question there is several ways to use it the best is :

```
$ gcc file.c -o file
and execute  with :
$ ./file
```

this  way of compilation will help you to reduce time of writing 
it's like compile and run in same time .

and here is  is the trick  :

we will create a bash script that do the both command in same time by taking the c file name as argument ;

1- create  a bash file his name `ccompiler` or `c` or what ever you want without any extension  .

2- past this code into this file  // the $1 in bash mean the first argument of script !

```
gcc $1.c -o $1
./$1
```

3- give this file permissions by this command :

`sudo chmod 755 ccompiler ;` #ccompiler or the name you chose .

4- put the file in `/usr/local/bin` to use it as a command #this is the directory of local scripts in linux .

5- be sure that you are in the directory were the c file you want to execute and run  ; in your case you have to be in  `/home/pi/Desktop/C/` to excute the command we write as command :

```
$ ccompiler cfile_name ;
```

ccompiler  : is the bash file name you choose

cfile_name : name of file you want to execute and run !! be sure to write it without extension .

Comment: .o files are **not** executable files. They are compiled object files that first need to be linked to become an executable (the picture even shows this). And saying you don't need to use *gcc* by putting it in a shell script is incorrect as well. you are still using the compiler (and that script does not offer any real speed-up, especially since it will be confusing if you have compiler errors)

Comment: And .h files are **not** libraries either. They are header files, containing definitions.

Comment: Not to mention that the way you say to use that shell script is wrong as well. If you type `ccompiler cfile_name.c` it will give an error as it will try to execute the following command `gcc cfile_name.c.c -o cfile_name.c`

Comment: i will change this too

Comment: your comment :
And saying you don't need to use gcc by putting it in a shell script is incorrect as well.

were did i said that ?

Comment: *"note : you don't have to use gcc as you do in the question there is several ways to use it the best is :"* - right before your shell script. Maybe it's just poor wording/phrasing

Comment: yes i am speaking about the way he used !! 
any correction ? :)

Comment: I still don't consider that script to be a good idea. It will only work for very simple programs (that consist of only one file) and in a worst case might encourage OP (and others reading the answer) to put all of their code into a single file. Further separation of the two steps (compiling and running) is a good idea in order to easier understand whether one has a compile time error or a runtime error (which may be hard for beginners to differentiate)

Comment: okey my friend write an answer it will be better than mine :) 
or just edit mine :)